# django categories: How to get children of a category using django-categories?

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-categories](https://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) to implement music related app. I want artist as my category and his/her songs as children

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
from categories.models import CategoryBase

class Artist(CategoryBase):
    cat = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

In templates, artist_details.html

```
{% extends 'base_post.html' %}
{% load category_tags %}
{% block page_content %}

<h1>{{ artist.name }}</h1>

{% if artist.children.count %}
    <h2>Subcategories</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for child in artist.children.all %}
        <li><a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

The template is getting rendered coz I can see artist's name. But i am unable to fetch the children. I checked the docs but I could not find much stuff related to fetching children.

There is data for both models in my DB, I added relevant info via admin interface. Can anyone tell me what I am missing ?

Also I open to using better packages. You can give any suggestions that implements categories.

SOLUTION: From django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls

thanks mariodev

Comment: I think when you subclass category model, you cannot use `children` anymore. Try using `song_set` instead.

Comment: By song_set are you referring to queryset ? If no can you explain further what u mean or gimme some useful web page link where i can dig further ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even using django-categories, you can't have songs as children of artists. Artists just do not form a category.

What you instead want is something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
from categories.models import CategoryBase

class MusicCategory(CategoryBase):
    # add extra fields, like images, "featured" and such here
    pass

class Artist(CategoryBase):
    name       = CharField(max_length=255,)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(MusicCategory, related_name="artists")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    slug        = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    artist      = models.ForeignKey(Artist, related_name="songs", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    categories  = models.ManyToManyField(MusicCategory, related_name="songs")
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and with some templates

```
{% extends 'base_post.html' %}
{% load category_tags %}
{% block page_content %}

<h1>{{ artist.name }}</h1>

{% if artist.songs.all.exists %}
    <h2>Songs</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for song in artist.songs.all %}
        <li><a href="{{ song.get_absolute_url }}">{{ song }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

REF: https://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/custom_categories.html#creating-custom-categories